# How does eutrophication yield lower levels of dissolved oxygen?

Tags: biochemistry, ecology, marine-biology, environment, limnology

Where do the oxygen go? Is it consumed by a particular species? Is just not enough being made? Please explain.

Comment: This question indicates no prior research by the OP. Even a simple google search provides the answer. For example, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutrophication#Mechanism_of_eutrophication).

Comment: @theforestecologist The question keeps its interest. Since algal bloom produces both oxygen and organic matter (whose decay consumes the same amount of oxygen) the question of where has all that oxygen gone and why is there a large net loss of oxygen is not answered by a simple Google search.

Answer (score 2):

[image: http://sbt.blob.core.windows.net/storyboards/v1621335/eutrophication.png]

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutrophication#Mechanism_of_eutrophication):

> Eutrophication arises from the oversupply of nutrients, which leads to over growth of plants and algae. After such organisms die, the bacterial degradation of their biomass consumes the oxygen in the water, thereby creating the state of hypoxia.

Answer (score 1):

The oxygen is used up by bacterial decay of the plants and algae that overgrow when there is too much phosphorus or nitrogen available; the plants grow so quickly that they compete with each other for sunlight.

Any basic source on eutrophication, even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutrophication), will talk about this extensively.